# NVIDIA GPU fan speed configuration only applies to 1 of 2 GPUs

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, fan

I have two NVIDIA GPUs, and I want to set the fan speed of each separately. When I use `nvidia-settings` to do this, I can only set the fan speed of `[gpu:0]`, and changes I make affect the device labeled 1 in `nvidia-smi`. Changes to `[gpu:1]` fan speed give normal (ie. non error) output, but have no effect.

- Why would changes to `[gpu:0]` affect device 1? Are the IDs in these labels supposed to match? What would be the label of device 0?
- `nvidia-smi` lists Xorg as a process running on *both* GPUs, but I have only one display, :0. Is it possible that the `[gpu:x]` identifiers are display specific, and that I need to start a new display? If so, how can I start a new display and specify that it should use my other GPU?
- I have tried running `Xvfb` to create a new display: `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &`. This did create a display :1, but if I try to use this display when I change fan settings, I get an error, `WARNING: NV-CONTROL extension not found on this Display.` Also see the exact fan command I used below.

---

Relevant information:

**NVIDIA-SMI Output**

```
Thu Aug 22 13:33:05 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.104      Driver Version: 410.104      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 35%   34C    P8    10W / 250W |   3741MiB / 10981MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 40%   45C    P2    71W / 250W |   2593MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     16282      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             6MiB |
|    0     22744      C   /opt/conda/bin/python                       1795MiB |
|    0     27845      C   /opt/conda/bin/python                       1935MiB |
|    1     16282      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            16MiB |
|    1     21781      C   /opt/conda/bin/python                       1215MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Snippet of XOrg.conf**

This is the part of my Xorg.conf file where I list both the GPUs. My understanding is that the configuration here is what creates the virtual desktop for each GPU, which in turn should allow me to set their fan speeds.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce RTX 2080 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**Command Used to Set Fan Speed**

```
sudo DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 nvidia-settings --verbose=all -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1 -a [fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=80
```

I have tried setting all the :0 and 0 usages to :1 and 1 in various places, but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently struggling with this issue as well. Before doing anything, make a backup of your current `xorg.conf`. Next, run the following command:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus --cool-bits=28
```

If you need `AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration` as `True`, run this command instead:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration
```

Save and reboot. This should allow you to control any GPU fan now. If you've been scripting this on boot, your new command will look like this:

```
nvidia-settings --verbose=all -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1 -a [fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=80 -a [gpu:1]/GPUFanControlState=1 -a [fan:1]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=80
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but after running these commands I am still not able to do anything to change GPU 0. If I run the exact configuration command you listed, only GPU 1 is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Python code:

```
import time
from pynvml import *

nvmlInit()

class Device:
  def __init__(self, index):
    self.index = index
    self.handle = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(index)
    self.name = nvmlDeviceGetName(self.handle)
    self.fan_count = nvmlDeviceGetNumFans(self.handle)

  def set_fan_speed(self, percentage):
    """ WARNING: This function changes the fan control policy to manual. It means that YOU have to monitor the temperature and adjust the fan speed accordingly. If you set the fan speed too low you can burn your GPU! Use nvmlDeviceSetDefaultFanSpeed_v2 to restore default control policy.
    """
    for i in range(self.fan_count):
      nvmlDeviceSetFanSpeed_v2(self.handle, i, percentage)
 
print(f"Driver Version: {nvmlSystemGetDriverVersion()}")
device_count = nvmlDeviceGetCount()
devices = [Device(i) for i in range(device_count)]

for device in devices:
  device.set_fan_speed(80)

try:
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
except:
  # reset to auto fan control
  for device in devices:
    for i in range(device.fan_count):
      nvmlDeviceSetDefaultFanSpeed_v2(device.handle, i)
  nvmlShutdown()
```

Note how on script exit we revert to default fan control.

Here is also [my gist](https://gist.github.com/AlexKordic/65f031b708177a01a002cc19f0d7298c) for updating fan speed in response to temperature change.